# Solution for HTTP 500 ERROR on my php pages

Tags: php, apache

I just uploaded some php files on my cpanel and one single html file.
I tried to load the html file which displays fine but the php files when I load them on my web browser are telling me HTTP ERROR 500.

So I checked my web server error log and it says

> home/wghlqqmxetvlogc/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command
> 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in
> the server configuration

I searched online for a solution and I learnt my server operates with Server API PRM/FastCGI instead of Apache . The solution was that I needed to comment out any php_flag that exists in my .htaccess file.
So I checked my .htaccess file but there exists no such thing as a php_flag on my htaccess.

Here is the code for my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Has anyone faced this issue before and came up with a solution? Please share!

Comment: Hmmm, this sounds a bit like an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). It might be that there's nothing wrong with your server, but your PHP script might have contained an error. Could you show the original PHP file which started this all? Alternatively try a very simple PHP file, one which you know works. Something like `<?php echo "I am simple and working.";`

Comment: Are you sure you checked the _correct_ .htaccess under the path the error message mentioned?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you!  A simple common mistake was the issue. I feel so stupid right now. It works now

Comment: I typed ```<? php``` instead of ```<?php```

Comment: Oh! Yes, that was stupid.  No, really, I'm glad you resolved the problem. We've all have been hunted by stupid mistakes at times. We don't all admit it though.